# Cannot find symbol error android compiling

Tags: java, android, compilation

I get an error cannot find symbol

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.theme_item, parent, false);
    row.setTag(new ViewHolder(row));
    return row;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ThemeItem themeItem = mDAOItem;
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    // int orientation =
    // context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    // holder.preview.setImageURI(themeItem.getPreviewUri(orientation));
    String hash = themeItem.getPreviewHash();   (this line seems to be the error)

    if (mBitmaps.containsKey(hash)) {
        holder.preview.setImageBitmap(mBitmaps.get(hash));
    } else {
        Log.w("Theme","Hit else");
        // make sure it is not null to fix bug caused by a shitty theme
        // provider
        if (hash == null || hash.isEmpty()) {// holder.preview.getDrawable()==null){
            // TODO: find a more suitable image
            holder.preview
                    .setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);
        } else {
            byte[] bitmap = Base64.decode(hash, 0);
            holder.preview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(bitmap, 0, bitmap.length));
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want a real and quick answer, you'd have to give some more info on your error. Please show more of your code (for example, what type of object is `themeItem`). Also, please include the full error stacktrace in your code.
Edit your question, and I'm sure you'll get an answer in no time.

Comment: Where is the exception trace? Please share that?

Comment: It means your 'LogCat', i.e the complete list of error messages that you see in the Log.

Comment: Cannot find symbol.. sounds like a compile error to me.. Please share the full error massage. and the line number (please give the line number we can refer to.. in the posted code. not the line number in your file) .. thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1):

http://pastie.org/7997386

vendor/tmobile/apps/ThemeChooser/src/com/tmobile/themechooser/ThemeChooser.java:345: cannot find symbol
           symbol  : method getPreviewHash()
            location: class com.tmobile.themes.provider.ThemeItem
            String hash = themeItem.getPreviewHash();
                                   ^